# Ruby class methods. Is it getting called on main object?

Tags: ruby

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Test
  def self.hello
    puts "I say hello"
  end

  def goodbye
    puts 'goodbye'
  end

  hello
  goodbye
end
```

This is my output:

```
 ruby class_methods.rb
I say hello
class_methods.rb:11:in `<class:Test>': undefined local variable or method `goodbye' for Test:Class (NameError)
    from class_methods.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

What is `hello` being called on? It looks like it does indeed get called but what is it being called on? I think it's being called on the main object... but why does that make sense? I thought class methods can only be called on the class object itself not a `main` object?

Comment: The ruby interpreter will read and execute your file/class from top to bottom. At the end of the class it execute the `hello` class method in your class. The class object isn't an instance of that class, so the execution of goodbye fails.

Comment: Well, if you already know that class methods can only get called on the class itself, and you already know that the call works, then … why do you think it is getting called on the main object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is hello being called on?

Whenever there isn't an explicit receiver, the receiver is `self`. So the call is implicitly:

```
self.hello
```

... where `self` is the class `Test`, on which you have just defined the `self.hello` method.

`goodbye` is not found because it is defined on an instance of class `Test`, not the class itself, where it's currently called.

Comment: So what/where is the `main` object?

Comment: @Jwan622, the context surrounding the `Test` class is an instance of `Object`, and that instance is named `main`. Try opening pry or irb and typing `self`, and you'll get the result `=> main`

Answer (score 2):

`def self.hello` is a class method

```
 def self.hello
    puts "I say hello"
  end

 hello or Test.hello
 #I say hello
```

`def goodbye` is a instance method of class of `Test`

```
  def goodbye
    puts 'goodbye'
  end

 Test.new.goodbye  #instance of Test
 #goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` defines class methods whereas defining just a method without self will mean that the method is an instance method, therefore, calling `goodbye` will raise an error because there is no receiver, an instance of the `Test` class is needed to *send* that message or call that method.

When ruby parses the class and evaluates the code it can call `hello` because there is no need to instantiate an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining hello as class method whereas goodbye is an instance method.

```
class Test
  def self.hello
    puts "I say hello"
  end
  ...
end
```

This class method since you are calling hello on self, which is Test class, so you can call hello by `Test.hello`.

```
...
def goodbye
    puts 'goodbye'
end
```

To call goodbye method, since this is an instance method, you need to create an instance of Test by using `Test.new` method. Therefore, you need to use `Test.new.goodbye` to call goodbye method.